# Why can I not create this unique_ptr with deleter?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I was using SDL and came across a problem which I cannot solve. I want to keep the textures (pointer to struct) in a `std::map` where I use an `std::string` as a key and a `std::unique_ptr<texture, void(*)(texture*)>` as the value. I have to use the deleter in the `std::unique_ptr`, because the textures have to be freed by a certain function. The textures are also created by another function. I simplified the code to what i have below:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

int* new_int(){ return new int; }
void delete_int(int* p){ delete p; }

typedef std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)> int_ptr;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int_ptr> the_map;
    the_map[1] = int_ptr(new_int(), delete_int);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this code in Visual Studio 2012 I get the following error:

```
error C2338: unique_ptr constructed with null deleter pointer.
```

Which I find odd, since I provided `delete_int` as a deleter pointer.
Any help is welcome, and so are different approaches.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The construction of element `[n]` requires default-constructible types, of which `unique_ptr` is not one. Consider using `.insert()` with a `value_type` instantiation instead. Something like `the_map.insert(std::map<int, int_ptr>::value_type(1, int_ptr(new_int(), delete_int)));`

Comment: @WhozCraig `map::emplace` is IMHO the preferred solution, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because using `map::operator[]` requires the value type to be default constructible, which a `unique_ptr` in this case is not. The stored pointer to the object of `unique_ptr` may be empty, but the deleter, if it is a pointer, may not be 0. You can check this with

```
the_map[1];
```

or even just

```
int_ptr p;
```

which will give you the exact same error.

The solution is to use [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
the_map.emplace(1, int_ptr(new_int(), delete_int));
```

If that is not possible because it is not implemented in your environment, you can use [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

```
the_map.insert(std::make_pair(1, int_ptr(new_int(), delete_int)));
```

or the more verbose but slightly more efficient

```
the_map.insert(std::map<int, int_ptr>::value_type(1, int_ptr(new_int(), delete_int)));
```

Comment: or also `the_map.insert({1, int_ptr(new_int(), delete_int))})` (note the {})

Comment: @DaveS It might be less efficient than `emplace`, but it is actually an alternative to `insert` in case `emplace` is not available. Nice.